# XML export via BCP Bulk Export

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure

I got a table tblScan with some varbinary data. I want to export this table to an XML-file so I can insert this in SQL azure with BCP Bulk insert. ( **BTW is it even possible to convert varbinary data to XML ??** )

I'm doing:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000)
SET @String='bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblScan FOR XML RAW, XMLSCHEMA" queryout C:\Users\DAAGEU\Desktop\tblScanOutput.xml -c -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @String
```

But I got this output error:

[image: Output error]

**Are there any other solutions to do this?**

Comment: Error says could not open a connection but I'm using a trusted connection or?

Comment: This looks like it's not a problem with whatever you're doing with Xml but with connecting to the server at all. Does a simpler query (eg `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tblScan`) work?

Comment: OK, so this isn't a problem with varbinary or xml; it's a problem getting `bcp` to run in an Azure environment. You might want to edit your title and question to reflect this.

Comment: No no for now I just want to generate an XML file to my desktop which I'll later insert in SQL azure via BCP Bulk insert. My prob is that I Can't generate the XML file due BCP Bulk export

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually a problem with VarBinary and XML (in SQL 2008 R2):

> FOR XML EXPLICIT and RAW modes currently do not support addressing
>   binary data as URLs in column SomeComlumn.  Remove the column, or use the BINARY BASE64 mode, or create the URL directly using the 'dbobject/TABLE[@PK1="V1"]/@COLUMN' syntax.

Quick searching showed [this post](http://en.csharp-online.net/XML_and_ADO.NET%E2%80%94FOR_XML_RAW).

Is there particluar reason that you want to export in XML? I have been using bcp using the default binary output and there are no issues with VarBinary fields. Binary files are quite smaller then the XML files. And if you don't want to do any manipulation between export and import, I suggest that you use binary files.

Try changing your query to:

```
SET @String='bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblScan FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64" queryout C:\Users\DAAGEU\Desktop\tblScanOutput.xml -c -T'
```

However, as seen by the logs, your current issue is the login. You are using trusted connection, but do you know which identity is running the bcp process, when it is spawned by the SQL Server engine? It would most probably the SQL Server identity, which I guess does not have access to the database/table (and most probaly is Local System or Network Service). If you still want to make this using SQL query, and not a batch file (.bat or .cmd) I suggest that you use explicit login credentials (SQL Server auth) and not trusted connection.