# Msg 6522, Level 16 but no error message selecting from sys.all_columns

Tags: .net, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I'm running a SQLCLR function with `SqlConnection("context connection=true")`.

In some cases, I get the exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalRead(Boolean ignoreNonFatalErrors)
>   at ObjDb.Functions.ObjDb(String db, String schema, String obj, String col, String val)
>
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   Error Number:200,State:4,Class:25

That happens every time with same query at same record number.

With connection

```
SqlConnection(@"Server=" + @"localhost\sqldeveloper16" + ";Database=" + db + ";Integrated Security=true;connect Timeout = 50")
```

I never get this error, and all is fine.

I don't understand why.

Then I tried same CLR on SQL Server 2008 and there are no problem...what do I have to check?!?!

Could this be a SQL Server 2016 bug?!

This my class

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ObjDb
{
    public partial class Functions
    {
        [SqlFunction
        (
            //DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,//serve x accedere alle tabelle del db, altrimenti accede solo a qlle di sistema...
            SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read,
            FillRowMethodName = "columns_ok",
            TableDefinition = "c1 nvarchar(max), node nvarchar(max)"
        )
        ]

        public static IEnumerable ObjDb(String db, String schema, String obj, String col, String val)
        {
            List<String> rows = new List<String>();//List<Object[]> rows = new List<Object[]>();
            //List<tuple.t2<String, String>> rows = new List<tuple.t2<String, String>>();

            SqlCommand command = null;// = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlConnection conn = null;// new SqlConnection("context connection=true");

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");//new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + @"localhost\sqldeveloper16" + ";Database=" + db + ";Integrated Security=true;connect Timeout = 50"); //new SqlConnection("context connection=true");//
                conn.Open();

                String query;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("where 0=0");

                if ((col != null && !col.Equals("")) && (val != null && !val.Equals("")))
                {
                    String[] cols = col.Split(',');
                    String[] vals = val.Split(',');

                    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(cols.Length, vals.Length); i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" and [").Append(cols[i]).Append("]='").Append(vals[i].Replace("'", "''")).Append("'");
                    }
                    //filter = "where 0=0 " + sb.ToString();
                    //filter = "where [" + col + "]='" + val + "'";
                }
                //estrazione inline dell xml (un xml x ogni riga)
                //"BINARY BASE64" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801697/xml-export-via-bcp-bulk-export - bug 2008R2, converte il varbinary in ascii
                query =
                "select (select t.* for xml raw('root'),BINARY BASE64) " +
                "from [" + db + "].[" + schema + "].[" + obj + "] t " +
                sb.ToString(); ;//filter;

                command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                //command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //rows.Add(new tuple.t2<String, String>("", (String)dr[0]));
                    rows.Add((String)dr[0]);
                }
                return rows;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                rows.Add(e.ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(4000, e.ToString().Length)));
                return  rows;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command != null)
                    command.Dispose();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
        private static void columns_ok(object resultObj, out SqlString node)
        {
            //String res = (String)resultObj;

            node = (String)resultObj;
        }
    }
}
```

and then from Sql

```
select *
from dbo.objdb('test','sys','all_columns',null,null)
```

result is (5248 records and last contains the exception, i posted only last 3):

```
<root object_id="-103402673" name="similarity_index_page_count" column_id="4" system_type_id="127" user_type_id="127" max_length="8" precision="19" scale="0" is_nullable="1" is_ansi_padded="0" is_rowguidcol="0" is_identity="0" is_computed="0" is_filestream="0" is_replicated="0" is_non_sql_subscribed="0" is_merge_published="0" is_dts_replicated="0" is_x005F_xml_document="0" xml_collection_id="0" default_object_id="0" rule_object_id="0" is_sparse="0" is_column_set="0" generated_always_type="0" generated_always_type_desc="NOT_APPLICABLE" is_hidden="0" is_masked="0"/>
<root object_id="-103085222" name="database_id" column_id="1" system_type_id="56" user_type_id="56" max_length="4" precision="10" scale="0" is_nullable="0" is_ansi_padded="0" is_rowguidcol="0" is_identity="0" is_computed="0" is_filestream="0" is_replicated="0" is_non_sql_subscribed="0" is_merge_published="0" is_dts_replicated="0" is_x005F_xml_document="0" xml_collection_id="0" default_object_id="0" rule_object_id="0" is_sparse="0" is_column_set="0" generated_always_type="0" generated_always_type_desc="NOT_APPLICABLE" is_hidden="0" is_masked="0"/>
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalRead(Boolean ignoreNonFatalErrors)     at ObjDb.Functions.ObjDb(String db, String schema, String obj, String col, String val)  ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  Error Number:200,State:4,Class:25
```

thank in advance!!

UPDATE:
i don't know why, but the problem is the column "`collation_name`" ONLY ON SQL 2016.

i tried to remove it from the query and no exceptions...

Comment: Can you post your SQLCLR code as well as the full error message. Error 0x80131904 can be a couple of things, one being that the server cannot be found, but it can also be other errors. Also, what do you mean with "the same query at same record number" (same query I understand but same record number???).

Comment: so, clr give me a number of record (for ex 5249) each time for that query and then throw an exception.
i tried with 2 sql 2016 and same problem, with 2008r2 all fine...

Comment: What _exact_ query is it executing? Please post at least that query into the question, but better would be to also include the .NET code.

Comment: Without having looked too much into it, I do think that your error-handling masks the actual error.

Comment: this is what .net give me...i think is a server setting, that happens on sql 2016 istance, not on 2008.
i tried 3 sql 2016 instances, give error only on these...i don't know what i have to check...

Comment: It _might_ have to do with ` return rows;` being inside of the `try` instead after it. Though I just tested this code on SQL Server 2012 and it works just fine. Will test on 2016 next.

Comment: What is your database's default Collation? Also, you shouldn't be using `String` for input params. You should be using `SqlString` and access the .NET string value via the `.Value` property of each param.

Comment: I did reproduce this on 2016. Am looking into it. Interesting: the error does not occur when selecting from `sys.columns`, just `sys.all_columns`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from one particular row in `sys.system_columns`, which is one of the two internal tables queried in the `sys.all_columns` system catalog view.

This error also appears to only happen if the `collation_name` field is used in a query selecting from either `sys.system_columns` or `sys.all_columns`.

Testing subsets of rows, I was able to determine that the error only occurs for one row. That object is:

[sys.pdw_nodes_pdw_physical_databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-pdw-nodes-pdw-physical-databases-transact-sql)

This row is *not* present in SQL Server 2012 (I have not tested anything besides 2012 SP3 and 2016 SP1), and there are no errors there at all.

The O.P. mentioned that this error only occurs when the `collation_name` field is selected. Looking at that field for that particular row, it is `NULL`. Certainly there is nothing wrong with a `NULL` since so many other rows shown `NULL` for `collation_name`. What is different for this one row is that the datatype is `sysname`, which is an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`, which is a string type and hence should always have a non-`NULL` Collation. I'm not sure how it is that this column, `physical_name`, has a `NULL` Collation, but it is the only string column with a `NULL` Collation in SQL Server 2016, and there are none in SQL Server 2012.

Why the error? Well, the real error is:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 406
>   A.NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ObjDb":
>     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalRead(Boolean ignoreNonFatalErrors)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.Read()
>       at ObjDb.Functions.ObjDb(String db, String schema, String obj, String col, String val)

Notice how there is no actual error message! Weird. Not sure how that happens, but the `collation_name` field is actually the following expression:

`convert(sysname, ColumnPropertyEx(object_id, name, 'collation')) AS collation_name`

The `ColumnPropertyEx` function is undocumented, so there isn't much to go on.

I suspect that this is a bug, of sorts, where `ColumnPropertyEx` raises a low-level error, low enough to not to show up as an error in SSMS. However, the in-process connection (i.e. `Context Connection = true`) seems to be very sensitive and actually catches whatever is happening with `ColumnPropertyEx`.

Now, avoiding this *should* be a simple matter of adding the following condition to the `WHERE` clause *if* the schema name is `sys` and the object_name is `all_columns` or `system_columns`:

```
NOT (user_type_id IN (231, 256) AND collation_name IS NULL)
```

However, since those are views, it seems to process all rows before apply those filters.

SO, the one way that I found around this is to filter on the `id` fields using the following:

```
NOT (t.[object_id] = -103085222 AND t.[column_id] = 2)
```

The only real problem now is that I don't know if that `object_id` is the same across all versions of SQL Server 2016, nor in SQL Server 2017 (I haven't checked there yet).

**What / Where is the real bug?**

While it seems like the `ColumnPropertyEx` function should probably not be behaving as it is, I think the primary problem is that the 3 columns for `pdw_nodes_pdw_physical_databases` should be returning from `sys.all_columns` in the first place. `pdw_nodes_pdw_physical_databases` isn't even available outside of Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse. In fact, it is strange enough that the object name `pdw_nodes_pdw_physical_databases` is returned by the `OBJECT_NAME` function, yet does not show up in `sys.all_objects` ;-).

Comment: hi, so thanks for the answer and the precision with which you wrote! but, my last doubt is why in "Context Connection = true" sql raise exception instead in SSMS. because if i exec the query "select collation_name from test.sys.all_columns" in SSMS is fine, in CLR not, but fin in CLR with a new connection like "SqlConnection(@"Server=" + @"localhost\sqldeveloper16" + ";Database=" + db + ";Integrated Security=true;connect Timeout = 50")"...
what i want to say is, the result is correct in SSMS or the exception is not caught and the result has less records as really should has?

Comment: FYI I stumbled across this too, and chased the wrong things, until I realized this is a client/driver problem. It happens with SSMS 16, for example, but not any newer version. https://sqlblog.org/2019/12/18/metadata-meets-metadata

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the problem, so my work around is to add a new parameter where define the columns to extract.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ObjDb
{
    public partial class Functions
    {
        [SqlFunction
        (
            //DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,//serve x accedere alle tabelle del db, altrimenti accede solo a qlle di sistema...
            SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read,
            FillRowMethodName = "columns_ok",
            TableDefinition = "c1 nvarchar(max), node nvarchar(max)"
        )
        ]

        public static IEnumerable ObjDb(String db, String schema, String obj, String col, String col, String val)
        {
            List<String> rows = new List<String>();//List<Object[]> rows = new List<Object[]>();
            //List<tuple.t2<String, String>> rows = new List<tuple.t2<String, String>>();

            SqlCommand command = null;// = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlConnection conn = null;// new SqlConnection("context connection=true");

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");//new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + @"localhost\sqldeveloper16" + ";Database=" + db + ";Integrated Security=true;connect Timeout = 50"); //new SqlConnection("context connection=true");//
                conn.Open();

                String query;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("where 0=0");

                if ((col != null && !col.Equals("")) && (val != null && !val.Equals("")))
                {
                    String[] cols = col.Split(',');
                    String[] vals = val.Split(',');

                    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(cols.Length, vals.Length); i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" and [").Append(cols[i]).Append("]='").Append(vals[i].Replace("'", "''")).Append("'");
                    }
                    //filter = "where 0=0 " + sb.ToString();
                    //filter = "where [" + col + "]='" + val + "'";
                }

            String headers;

            if (col != null && !col.Equals(""))
            {
                headers = col;
            }
            else
            {
                headers = "t.*";
            }
                //estrazione inline dell xml (un xml x ogni riga)
                //"BINARY BASE64" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801697/xml-export-via-bcp-bulk-export - bug 2008R2, converte il varbinary in ascii
                query =
                "select (select " + headers + " for xml raw('root'),BINARY BASE64) " +
                "from [" + db + "].[" + schema + "].[" + obj + "] t " +
                sb.ToString(); ;//filter;

                command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                //command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //rows.Add(new tuple.t2<String, String>("", (String)dr[0]));
                    rows.Add((String)dr[0]);
                }
                return rows;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                rows.Add(e.ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(4000, e.ToString().Length)));
                return  rows;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command != null)
                    command.Dispose();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
        private static void columns_ok(object resultObj, out SqlString node)
        {
            //String res = (String)resultObj;

            node = (String)resultObj;
        }
    }
}
```

what i tried:

```
select *
from dbo.objdb('test','sys','all_columns',null,null,null)
```

error

```
select *
from dbo.objdb('test','sys','all_columns','collation_name',null,null)
```

error

```
select *
from dbo.objdb('test','sys','all_columns','object_id,name,column_id,system_type_id,user_type_id,max_length,precision,scale,is_nullable,is_ansi_padded,is_rowguidcol,is_identity,is_computed,is_filestream,is_replicated,is_non_sql_subscribed,is_merge_published,is_dts_replicated,is_xml_document,xml_collection_id,default_object_id,rule_object_id,is_sparse,is_column_set,generated_always_type,generated_always_type_desc,encryption_type,encryption_type_desc,encryption_algorithm_name,column_encryption_key_id,column_encryption_key_database_name,is_hidden,is_masked',null,null)
```

(all columns without "collation_name")
FINE!

```
 select *
 from dbo.objdb('test','sys','columns','collation_name',null,null)
```

FINE O.o

Comment: Problem has to do with `sys.system_columns` catalog view. I am looking further into it.

Comment: yes, with select * from dbo.objdb('test','sys','system_columns','collation_name',null,null) i have same problem...but why in sql 2016 only?!?! and why not with sys.columns??

Comment: I found it...will write it up soon...it's one particular row in `sys.system_columns`.